# Magazine possible in Craft?

Tags: categories, craft-features

I have been a wordpress user for the longest time, a friend of mine now uses Craft, I took a look at his backend and really liked the way he creates his content in it. I also like that it uses Twig.

I watched some of the Craft movies on the website about the entry types, structures etc. but it would be of some help if some experienced user could help me with the question if Craft is the right choice for me:

I have a small magazine website about movies, so I would need the following structure:
- Movies (a list of movies, when I click on a movie I would like to have a list of all news, reviews regarding to this movie)
- News 
- Reviews
- Directors (a list of directors, when I click on the director I would like to display a list of all of this directors movies)

Is this possible out of the box with Craft CMS? I'd be thankful for any hint on how you would realize this.

Best regards
Florian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do all of that with Craft CMS, the thing you're searching for are "related entries" where you can relate news to a certain movie ... director ... basically you can relate everything to everything.

You can find more information about relationships here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/relations

Comment: You are welcome! :)